# Firefox addon dev: communication between scripts -> variables not updated

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm developing a simple addon on Firefox that counts how many instances of an element in a page match some criteria (eg. name="btnK") and displays it on a sidebar.

If I understood correctly, to interact with the page's DOM I must use port.emit/port.on and content scripts, so i did this:

1) the sidebar.js script emits a signal to the index.js (the main addon script) that request a "instances count";
2) index.js emits a signal to a content script (countScript.js) attached to the page which counts the instances (and it works well);
3) countScript.js emits a response to index.js with the number requested;
4) index.js emits the answer ("instancesCounted", n) and sidebar.js listen to it (addon.port.on("instancesCounted"), function(n){ .. });

I tested via console.log all these passages and they all works (the numbers always match the elements on the page), but then I have to use that number (let's call it "currI") to print it on the sidebar. When I try to do that it shows that currI is undefined. I thought it was a problem of scope and tried to use a global variable but didn't work either.

Any suggestion?

Here's some code:

sidebar.js:

```
var currI = 0;

function printInstances(){
  elName = $("#inputNewLoc").val();  // just get the element name in order to count it later
  currI = countInstances(elName); // from here currI is undefined     
  console.log("currI", currI);
  [..]
}

function countInstance(elName){
  currI = addon.port.emit("countInstances", elName);
  console.log(currI); // here shows correctly the number of istances
}
```

index.js

```
var sidebar = require("sdk/ui/sidebar").Sidebar({
id: 'my-sidebar', 
title: 'My sidebar',
url: self.data.url("sidebar.html"),

onAttach: function(worker) {    
  worker.port.on("countInstances", function(elName){      
    var worker2 = tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("countScript.js")
    });
    worker2.port.emit("execCount", elName);  
    worker2.port.on("instancesCounted", function(n){        
      worker.port.emit("instancesCounted", n); 
      console.log(n); // n is the correct number of instances here       
    })              
  })    
}
```

countScript.js

```
self.port.on("execCount", function(elName) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByName(elName);
  n = elements.length;  
  self.port.emit("instancesCounted", n); // all seems to work fine here
});
```

Comment: you got all this asynchronous `emit` and `on` between the scripts happening - yet somehow you fall one step short of making it work and expect (incorrectly) `addon.port.emit` to be synchronous in one place, but not the others - I can't see how the correct number could possibly be shown where you say it is in `sidebar.js`... I think you are mistaken - nowhere do you pass on the counted instances to `sidebar.js`

Comment: @Jaromanda I think i got the basic concept of asynchronous communication and that port.on/emit are async method of passing data.
In fact I tried some variants until i got to the one i posted,
You're right about I forgot to copy a part of sidebar.js:
`addon.port.on("instancesCounted", function(n){
      currI = n; 
      console.log(currI)   // here the number is CORRECT 
    })`

What I can't understand is why currI ends being undefined and not = 0;
Btw thank you for your help!

Comment: it ends up undefined because of this line `currI = countInstances(elName);` and `function countInstance` does not return anything (i.e. the return value is **undefined**)

Comment: you're right. The how do you pass the updated currI value to the printInstances functions? I am confused :O

Comment: just like in `index.js`, in  `sidebar.js` you want to do something like `addon.port.on("instancesCounted", function(n){` _do something with n_ `});` ... I'm confused as to how you do it so right between `index.js` and `countScript.js`, yet `sidebar.js` seems to confuse you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion for sidebar.js:

```
var currI = 0;

function printInstances(){
  elName = $("#inputNewLoc").val();  // just get the element name in order to count it later

  addon.port.on("instancesCounted", function(n){ do something with n 
      console.log("n", n); // 
  });

  addon.port.emit("countInstances", elName);
}
```

Comment: you really helped me! as you said, the focal point was the "asynchronousness" of port.on/emit. thank you very much!